# Qt Layouts after Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I've been developing software for my own use. Recently I've had someone ask for a copy. However, I designed the GUI for my monitor size (meaning all of the widgets are fixed). I've figured out enough to put small dialog widgets in layouts. Now I need to put the main window in a layout. When I do though I cant get the widgets to be the sizes that you see in the image.

Any help?
[image: Screenshot of GUI]

[image: Screenshot of layout]

[image]

Comment: Do you want that the 'star' image will be stretched to the right side?

Comment: I would like for everything to grow while keeping the current proportions. By the way... that's a single exposure image directly out of a telescope.

Comment: Read about the [Qt layout management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)